# Duplicate question but different answers?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday, I asked this [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/96297/63121) and the overall theme of the answers provided was "No, don't do it". A user directed me to this [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/25861/should-i-inform-my-potential-employer-about-a-bug-in-their-application) and the overall theme was essentially "Do it, but do it nicely".

The two questions are nearly identical, but the answers provided are not. How can we improve answers in situations like this for users of the site?

Answer (score 4):

> The two questions are nearly identical, but the answers provided are
>   not. How can we improve answers in situations like this for users of
>   the site?

You seem to be assuming that there is "one true answer" for every question.

In a Q&A site like The Workplace, that is almost never the case. If you ask a question 10 times, you may well get 100 answers.

That's just "the way it is", IMHO.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I just want to get an understanding of this site before I invest time in it. The SE sites I'm active in there's usually only one right answer.

Comment: @MichaelC. - Yup. In many more technical sites, there is often one technical answer. But on a site that deals with more squishy topics like The Workplace, there are often many viable answers. While some of us may feel strongly about one answer in particular (sometimes indicated by upvotes), others feel equally strong about a competing answer. In human activities that is often the case. I hope you'll still find The Workplace useful.

Comment: Small niggle: Workplace and SE as a whole is not a forum but a Q&A site.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite possible to get different, valid answers to the same question. The intent of this site is not to tell you whst you should do, but to give you the *reasons* so you can make an informed decision yourself.

Every situation is different, different actions may be necessary. By giving you options, you can make a decision based on your particular circumstances.

Comment: I completely agree with you. But let's say the question I posted was closed as dupe (which it should be) before any answers were posted. Then I would have viewed only the answers on the other question and not this one. Which means I would have missed out on these points of views...

Comment: Unfortunately it happens, hopefully not often, but it does.  That's why these sites should only be a guide; sometimes the answer is obvious, other times there is a degree of flexibility. People answer from their experiences, which may or may not reflect your situation.

Comment: If that's the case, then should there even be a "primarily opinion based" flag? Every has different experiences and opinions, right?

Comment: When it crosses from experience to opinion, then there is a problem. Justifications become personal not professional, and can be a thousand different answers. Experience tends to fall into clear categories with specific reasons.